# What changes need to be made for the new local receipt validation requirement using SHA-256?

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, appstore-sandbox

I have an old app that was built using Objective-C and uses [this library](https://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore) for local receipt validation for IAPs.

Recently Apple announced that local receipt validation code must change from SHA1 to SHA256 as described in: [TN3138: Handling App Store receipt signing certificate changes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/technotes/tn3138-handling-app-store-receipt-signing-certificate-changes).

I read the document but I'm still not clear on what exactly I'm supposed to change in the code. I tried changing [the hashing algorithm in the verify receipt method](https://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore/blob/303b1e9625a80b21e195e7a58034f33a63edbeb1/RMStore/Optional/RMAppReceipt.m#L194) from:

```
    SHA1((const uint8_t*)data.bytes, data.length, (uint8_t*)expectedHash.mutableBytes);
```

to:

```
    SHA256((const uint8_t*)data.bytes, data.length, (uint8_t*)expectedHash.mutableBytes);
```

But the computed hash was different than the one in the receipt. Using the original `SHA1` the computed hash equals the one in the receipt.

According to the article linked above, the Sandbox should have updated certificates that work with the new SHA-256 hash since the 20th of June, 2023.

So I'm not sure what I should be doing to make sure the app and all IAPs work fine by the 14th of August when this change goes live. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does your code check the creation date in asn 1 field type 12 when determining which algorithm to use?